# Cannot restrict remote access to Postgres database using pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database running on a remote server, and I want to restrict access to the database so that it can only be accessed from a specific IP address, which belongs to my backend service.

To achieve this, I have edited the pg_hba.conf file on the Postgres server to include the IP address of my backend server in the host line. However, after reloading the configuration file, I am still able to connect to the database from other IP addresses, which should not be allowed.

I am unsure why the IP whitelisting is not working as expected and would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

In order to restrict remote access to the Postgres database only to my backend service's IP address, I added the following line to the pg_hba.conf file on the Postgres server:

`host    all    all    <backend-server-ip>/32    md5`

I then reloaded the configuration file using the pg_ctl -D /path/to/postgres/data/ reload command, but I am still able to connect to the database from other IP addresses.

My expectation was that the Postgres server would only allow connections from the IP address I specified in the pg_hba.conf file and deny connections from all other IP addresses. However, this is not the case and I am still able to connect to the database from other IP addresses.

Comment: Some other line in the file must be matching these other connections.

Comment: @RichardHuxton but i passed only single line there

Comment: Look in the log file.  Maybe your changes did not apply due to an error.  Or do a restart rather than a reload.

Comment: More information needed. **Add answers to following as update to question** 1) Postgres version. 2) OS and version 3) How was Postgres installed? 4) Are you sure you are modifying the correct file? I have seen quite a few cases where people changed the sample `pg_hba.conf` file not the one associated with the Postgres instance.

Comment: Postgres version: Postgres 11.5
OS and version: Ubuntu(Postgres pod is running on k8s)
Postgres was installed using the official Bitnami image on a remote server.
Yes, I am modifying the correct pg_hba.conf file associated with the Postgres instance. I have verified this by checking the data_directory setting in the postgresql.conf file and verifying that the pg_hba.conf file is located in the same directory.(SHOW hba_file)

Comment: @jjanes i try to restart but when i run pg_ctl -D /bitnami/postgresql/data/ restart
then my pod restart and again come up with default configuration that is something like this
host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host     all             all             ::/0                    md5
local    all             all                                     md5
host     all             all        127.0.0.1/32                 md5
host     all             all        ::1/128                      md5

Comment: I'm not familiar with these pod things.  are you saying that when you restarted the database, it destroyed the entire container and reinitialized it, losing the changes you made to the pg_hba?

Comment: @jjanes   correct